# Reading a file on python returns an empty string

Tags: python, file

I have been trying to read a file in python, the thing is that it returns an empty string. Here is the code:

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    content = f.readlines()
    print(content) #prints nothing
```

note: It's a really big file, is that a problem?

Comment: hmmm just did it but its still the same

Comment: Are you confident that there are some data inside the `data.txt` file? If-Then Can you provide the data and some more code?

Comment: yeah, there is data

Comment: is it a problem if the file is 4tb? Does that overwork the program?

Comment: That is the whole code, the file is a data holder for my schools registered kids in a program. The file size is 4tb

Comment: Fixed: the file was too big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. change `f.readlines()` to `file.readlines()` This is only a typo. But I don't know why you don't get the error here. I think you open another file as f And You get the empty string here 'cause if you try to read a file more than once, you got an empty string except for the first time.
2. As you say the file size is `4TB`, This could be the problem because of [`Max File Size In Python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134338/max-size-of-a-file-python-can-open)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your text file name is the proper one, but most important, you need to provide full path of the file, in case it is not in the same directory as the script.

Comment: It is in the same directory. I wonder whats the problem :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So I had this same issue with when I read a file using `with open`, as all it would do was return nothing even though the txt file was in the same directory and was full of content.

```py
file_path = r"C:\Users\windowsuser\Downloads\folder1\folder2\textfile.txt"
    
try:
    file = open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    content = file.read()
    print("File contents (visible):\n", content)
        
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
finally:
    if 'file' in locals():
        file.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    print(content) #prints nothing
```

This should work i think

Comment: it still dosent work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).